# Emulate \hfill in LaTeX equations?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I have a set of equations, where each line consists of a formula and an explanation (info about indices). Now, let's say the structure looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\lw}{\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    &\framebox[0.4\lw]{Formula 1} & \framebox[0.3\lw]{Info 1}& \\
    &\framebox[0.7\lw]{Formula 1} & \framebox[0.1\lw]{Info 1}& \\
    &\framebox[0.5\lw]{Formula 1} & \framebox[0.2\lw]{Info 1}&
\end{align*}
```

This results in two columns of widths `0.7\lw` and `0.3\lw`, so the equation will be too wide for the page: [image: output of the example code (too wide)]

Yet, no single line is wider than `0.8\lw`, so there is enough space if the two columns could "slide into each other", like this: [image: desired output]

In essence, I need some equiv. of `\hfill` between the two parts - but `\hfill` does not work here...

My question is whether there is a way to do this, i.e. to create a flexible space that would keep the left and right aligns. Note that the first align would typically be somewhere inside the formula, not in front of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't put the conditions flush right, but if you really insist, you can use `flalign`:

```
\begin{flalign*}
\qquad A&=\mathrlap{B} &\text{condition}\\
\qquad C&=\mathrlap{D} &\text{cond}\\
\qquad E&=\mathrlap{F} &\text{some longer condition}
\end{flalign*}
```

Change the `\qquad` into some other spacing command that suits your needs.

This needs the package **mathtools**

Comment: Thanks, this helped! (Ironically, I looked at mathtools today, to check \smashoperator, but have not thought of this..)